# How can js code be split across multiple files

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change the HTML code on the button click. Is there any other way to accomplish this? The issue I have faced is that over time ex1,ex2 codes get bigger and it becomes hard to read due to a text being a string.

```
<button onclick="test (1)">
click
</button>
<button onclick="test (2)">
click
</button>
<div id="ex1"></div>
```

```
const faq = {
ex1: `<button>1</button>`,
ex2: `<button>2</button>`
}

function test (number) {
if (number == 1){
document.getElementById("ex1").innerHTML = (faq.ex1);
}
if (number == 2){
document.getElementById("ex1").innerHTML = (faq.ex2);
}
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do after the user clicks?

Comment: The goal is to add the specific code from faq.ex1 or faq.ex2, but compared to the example I have sent the actual code I want to add is much bigger which makes it hard to read and I want to know if there is a way to store it somewhere else maybe for easier formatting. Because when the code is in the string format it's very hard to edit it.

Comment: Are you able to create additional files to import from?

Comment: Yes. Is there a way to keep this code in a separate file and import it from there? I just want it to look like a code and not like a string when I'm editing it.

Comment: There are two options. You can use the modern [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) to create a module, or you can simply make another `.js` file and import it like a normal script tag. Any variables you define in the `.js` file should be available to your main code as long as you do the import first

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will read the documentation in order to understand it.

Answer (score -2):

You just needed to remove the space between your function invocation.

**Instead of this:**

```
test (1)
```

**do this**

```
test(1)
```

Also you need to remove the space between your function name and the parenthesis

**Instead of this**

```js
function test ()
```

**Do this**

```js
function test()
```

Also you need to put your javascript into a script tag and make sure it comes before the html that calls it.
See example snippet

```html
<script>
const faq = {
ex1: `<button>1</button>`,
ex2: `<button>2</button>`
}

function test(number) {
if (number == 1){
document.getElementById("ex1").innerHTML = (faq.ex1);
}
if (number == 2){
document.getElementById("ex1").innerHTML = (faq.ex2);
}
}
</script>
<button onclick="test(1)">
click
</button>
<button onclick="test(2)">
click
</button>
<div id="ex1"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, that's not exactly what I was asking for, the main question is how do I make (faq.ex1) more readable once I increase the size of it. Hope this  comment clarifies my question.

Comment: The whitespace you are saying to correct actually has no impact on the code at all, and is completely valid. Try it in your dev console: `console.log ('this works')`